# Checking for nan with try/with in Ocaml

Tags: error-handling, pattern-matching, try-catch, ocaml

My aim is to compute the average of a float list. It can however occur that a list is empty, so the computation will be 0. /. 0. = nan but in those cases I want to return 0. instead of nan.
My code looks something like this:

```
let avg lst = 
    (*computation of sum of the list through the length of it *)
    try sum lst /. length lst 
  with 
   | Not_found -> 0.0
   | nan -> 0.
```

But my second with-case is seen as a variable instead of nan by the compiler.
How can I check for a nan in an try/with - Error block?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than catching an exceptional value after the fact, it will be cleaner to handle the empty list separately:

```ml
let avg = function
| [] -> 0.
| l -> sum l /. length l
```

If you really want to test for `nan`, you can do it with

```ml
let avg l = 
  let res = sum l /. length l in
  if Float.is_nan res then 0. else res
```

It is unclear to me why you are catching a `Not_found` exception, but if this is really necessary too, you can write:

```ml
let avg l =
  match sum l /. length l with
  | exception Not_found -> 0.
  | value ->
    if Float.is_nan value then 0. else value
```

Answer (score 2):

What does attempting to divide by `0.` actually return in OCaml?

```
utop # 1. /. 0.;;
- : float = infinity
```

Can we test for equality with this value?

```
utop # 1. /. 0. = infinity;;
- : bool = true
```

That leads us to something like:

```
try
  let avg = sum lst /. length lst in
  if avg <> infinity then avg
  else 0.
with
| Not_found -> 0.
```

But as of OCaml 4.02, we can incorporate exception handling into `match`, letting us express this perhaps a bit more clearly.

```
match sum lst /. length lst with
| avg when avg <> infinity -> avg
| _ -> 0.
| exception Not_found -> 0.
```

One thing you don't want to do is:

```
match sum lst /. length lst with
| infinity -> 0.
| avg -> avg
| exception Not_found -> 0.
```

When you use `match` this way, it is not testing if the value being matched equals `infinity`. Rather OCaml is binding the name `infinity` to that value. The above would return `0.` for *all cases* where the exception `Not_found` is not thrown.

In fact, if you try this, OCaml will issue a warning: `this match case is unused.` This indicates that the `avg` pattern can never be reached.

Comment: `x /. 0.` returns either `infinity`, `neg_infinity` or `nan`, depending on whether `x` is positive, negative or zero.